# Does facebook connect for iphone have encryption

Tags: iphone, facebook, encryption

Does facebook connect for iphone contain any encryption?

I tried searching on google but did not find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put no encryption when submitting for review and apple has approved it that way.